# ProcessBuilder launch main method in same project

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a Java class that needs to kick off a child process. The child process is a class containing a main() method within the same project. I have:

```
Class clazz = RunMQCommands.class;

String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
String path = System.getProperty("java.home");

ProcessBuilder pb = 
        new ProcessBuilder(path, "-cp", 
        classpath, 
        clazz.getCanonicalName());
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
int retCode = process.waitFor();
```

And this gives me a

```
CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

This is my first foray into ProcessBuilder. What am I doing wrong? I can kick off external things just fine (e.g. new ProcessBuilder("notepad"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path` variable will have a value of something like

```
/usr/share/Java/1.8/jre
```

That is not an executable file.

Find the location of your executable `java` file and give the value of that to your `path` variable.

Your `ProcessBuilder` should look like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = 
    new ProcessBuilder("/usr/share/Java/1.8/jre/java", "-cp", 
    classpath, 
    clazz.getCanonicalName());
```